# Filtering SignalR requests from ApplicationInsight

Tags: signalr, azure-application-insights

I've configured Application Insights on my web application however the telemetry is full of 'failed' requests from SingalR which makes spotting genuine issues difficult (see screenshot below). I want to filter out all SignalR requests and not send them to AI.

[image: AI SignalR]

I've created a Telemetry Processor (see code below based [on this example from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling)) and registered it in the ApplicationInsights.config file, this works as expected when debugging locally and prevents any SignalR events from being sent however it doesn't seem to have any effect once the web application published and running in IIS.

```
public class SignalRFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    public SignalRFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (!OKtoSend(item))
            return;
        else
            this.Next.Process(item);
    }

    private bool OKtoSend(ITelemetry item)
    {
        if (item is RequestTelemetry && ((RequestTelemetry)item).Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("signalr"))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that on the server the path is different or the casing (e.g. SignalR). The code looks ok to me.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked, I've just re-checked everything and I can't see any discrepancies between dev environment and what's published.  Once published it never seems to hit the filter at all.  I'll try creating a filter that throws an exception and see if that gets hit.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at these requests in Live Metrics Stream. For this particular view you can filter them out on demand. Feature is available in latest 2.4-beta (the stable version should be released soon). In this case you can click on Filter button and add proper filters to every stream. Similar behavior exists for charts:

[image]

Have you checked whether you see /signair/start in you Application Insights Analytics? It might be the case that you did filter them out successfully and they only show up in Live view.